# Package Memory Management in R

Tags: r, memory-management

I think there are some questions similar to mine, but I want to know
how the memory is managed on loading and unloading packages.

For example,

I tried

```
library(pryr)
mem_used()
35 MB
```

And

```
library(dplyr)
mem_used()
37.4 MB
```

Then, I tried

```
detach(package:dplyr)
unloadNamespace("dplyr")
mem_used()
38.3 MB
gc()
mem_used()
38.3 MB
```

I am not sure why memory is going up after unloadNameSapce was called, and

gc does not seem to work at all..

Is there a way to get memory back after unload or detach package?

If you know any, please help me out.